# Where I am making mistake with routing in Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

[Folder Structure of Nextjs which I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQVLe.png)

In my folder structure, I make one custom folder (src/app/pages) and in which I make files like Home and Footer. But access home with http://localhost:3000/pages/Home. I need http://localhost:3000/Home. How do I do this? I need to make layouts and page inside of pages folder for correct routing.

Comment: You should decide if you're using the app router or the pages router. `src/app/pages` is using the app router to define a route named pages, hence the result you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

In the new **App router** if you want to create a path like http://localhost:3000/Home , Your folder structure should look like `src/app/home/page.tsx`.

Here **home** is the route and **page.tsx or jsx** acts as **index** file.

For layout it will automatically use layout.tsx or jsx in the root directory.
This is the basic implementation if you want to play with **multiple layouts or dynamic routes** refer to Nextjs docs app router - [Nextjs Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing)